# How can I express pre- and post-multiplication as a single linear operator?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, representation-theory

An example is probably the best way to illustrate what I'm asking.

Let $G_1$ be $SO(3)$ and $G_2$ be $SO(3)$ as well.  Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, the combined action of $g_1 \in G_1$ and $g_2 \in G_2$ on $A$ is given simply by pre- and post-multiplying two matrices in $SO(3)$:

$(g_1, g_2)(A) = g_1 A g_2$

If I let $H$ be the group containing all pairs of elements from $G_1$ and $G_2$, then what are the irreducible representations of $H$?  And how can I convert $A$ into a form where it can be acted upon by an element in $H$ and then converted back into a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

(Apologies for the gross misuse of terminology here; I'm new to group theory; however, I'm trying to learn it quickly for my research.)

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is simply the Cartesian product of groups $G_1 \times G_2$, and the irreducible representations turn out to be [tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules) of the form $W_1 \otimes W_2$ where $W_i$ is an irreducible representation of $G_i$.

The particular case of $3 \times 3$ matrices turns out to be the representation $V \otimes V^*$ where $V$ is the standard $3$-dimensional real representation of $SO(3)$.